# @Annotations not running in selenium webdriver using testng

Tags: selenium, testng

```
@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {

  WebDriver driver;
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\chromedriver.exe");
  //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\geckodriver.exe");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  String baseurl = "http://demosite.center/wordpress/wp-login.php";
  driver.get(baseurl);
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@Test
public void VerifyLogin() {
  LoginClass login =  new LoginClass(driver);
  login.Username();
  login.Password();
  login.Submit();
}

@AfterTest
   public void afterTest() {
      driver.close();
   }

}
```

Only @Before test is running, @Test  and  @After Test is not running in selenium

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Its a good practice to attach error logs while asking questions.

Comment: Show us `LoginClass` Class file.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to the local variable driver in your before Test method. I guess, you have one more instance variable in the class with name as driver. You have assigned the local variable driver, not with instance variable.

May be you need to comment the local variable driver like,

```
@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest() {
  //WebDriver driver;
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\chromedriver.exe");
  //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\geckodriver.exe");
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  String baseurl = "http://demosite.center/wordpress/wp-login.php";
  driver.get(baseurl);
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```